# swift: auto cell height

Tags: ios, swift

I have `TableViewController`. In table cell I have `UIView`. I use storyboard to create constraints for `UIView`. I have this constraints:

[image]

For iPhone my cell looks fine. But For iPad I have this result:

[image]

My cell not stretch and hide part of `UIView` for iPad. How to fix it?

iPhone:

[image]

Comment: How does it look for iPhone?

Comment: Just a very quick tip as I'm in a bit of a rush, the aspect ratio constraint and the height constraint at the same time is not needed. Pick either one. Probably the height, aspect ratio will render fixed height compared to width. This alone might not solve your issue, though

Comment: @RakeshaShastri update question

Comment: Do you have the same storyboard and the same code for iPhone and iPad?

Comment: @Kerberos yes..

Comment: Please check in your Target General Deployment info, have you selected Universal?

Comment: @Skrew not helps

Comment: Can you add the code? Where you set the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` and the `estimatedRowHeight`.

Comment: @user2786 yes...

Comment: @Kerberos I use storyboard to set height. Not `UITableViewAutomaticDimension `

Comment: try to check row Height for iPad, or try to return hardcoded value to test?

Comment: @user2786 if I write `tableView.rowHeight = 367` all works fin only for iPad

Comment: You set the height and weight based on ratio. That's why height is different based on device screen size.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed and what I need to do?

Comment: You need to handle it programmatically. Set row height programmatically that already set for iPad. Add small check if the device is iPad or iPhone.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed But this is not what I want. Of course it is works. But I want to solve the problem in storyboard. For example if I add label in cell and change text (small or large) my cell will be change size automatically. Why I can't do this with my view?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Also if I use your tip I need to create check for all screens seizes. Not only iPad and iPhone check.

Comment: Not for all screen. Just check is iPhone or iPad that's it. I think it has no problem for different screens iPhone right?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed if I write ` tableView.rowHeight = 376.5` for iPad. On iPad 9,7 all works fine. But on iPad 12,9 I have same problem.

Comment: If this then you need to check screen size and set the rowHeight. Is there any equation based on device size?

Comment: Set the Height dynamically using UITableViewAutomaticDimension, don't use hardcode height value.